# How can I create a function that automatically takes data from Google Sheets and replaces the tags in a Slides template?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge

I am new to Google Apps Script and coding in general and wasn't entirely sure how to do this. I want to create code that allows me to create a new set of Google Slides based on a Slides template using the relevant rows from a Google Sheets document.

```
function generateNewSlides() {  
var wsID = "would insert worksheet URL ID here";
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById(wsID).getSheetByName("Data");
var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 5).getValues();

 >the above should get the relevant table from the sheet

data.forEach(function(info){
if(info[0]){

var firstname = info[0];
var surname = info[1];
var email = info[2];
var phone = info[3];
var image = info[4];
var presName = info[5];

>the above are columns where the different pieces of data would be taken from for the placeholders in the Slides template

var slidesTemplateID = "would insert slides template URL ID here";   
var slidesTemplate = SlidesApp.openById(slidesTemplateID);
var template = slidesTemplate.getSlides();
var folderID = "would insert desired folder ID for saving in here";

>the above should get me the Slides template

template.makeCopy(presName,DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID)); **>line where error occurred**
var newPresentation = DriveApp.getFilesByName(presName).next().getUrl();
var Presentation = SlidesApp.openByUrl(newPresentation);

>the above should create a copy and then open it

var shapes = (Presentation.getShapes());
 shapes.forEach(function(shape){
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{firstname}}',firstname);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{surname}}',surname);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{email}}',email);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{phone}}',phone);
   shape.getText().replaceAllText('{{presname}}', presName)

}); 
 >the above should replace all the placeholder tags in the template with the row data

} 
}); 

}
```

Above is the code I have so far. The worksheet I am extracting data from has columns: first name, surname, email address, phone number, image (URL), and presentation name. When I try to run it I encounter an error on line 37 where it says template.makeCopy is not a function, however I am certain .makeCopy should be able to create a copy for it, no?

My main questions are:
1) What should I change to make it work, generating a new set slides for each row in the worksheet?
2) How can I add images to it replacing placeholder tags I've added in squares (not textboxes) in the template?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue 1. makeCopy:

[makeCopy(name, destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)) is a method of the [class File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file), which belongs to the [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive), not to the [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides). In your code, `template` is a list of Slides (you retrieve it by calling the method [getSlides()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#getSlides()) from a [Presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation)). `makeCopy` cannot work here.

In order to make a copy of a `Presentation`, you should be using the `Drive Service` instead. You should replace these lines:

```js
var slidesTemplate = SlidesApp.openById(slidesTemplateID);
var template = slidesTemplate.getSlides();
```

With this one:

```js
var template = DriveApp.getFileById(slidesTemplateID);
```

#### Issue 2. Iterating through all shapes:

Next, you want to iterate through all shapes in your `Presentation`, and replace all placeholder tags with your desired text. In order to do that, you are using `Presentation.getShapes()`, which cannot work, since [getShapes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#getShapes()) is not a method of `Presentation`, but of [Slide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide).

You should first iterate through all `Slides` in the `Presentation`, and for each `Slide`, iterate through all [Shapes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape). You should replace these lines:

```js
var shapes = (Presentation.getShapes());
 shapes.forEach(function(shape){
   // Replacing text lines
});
```

With these ones:

```js
Presentation.getSlides().forEach(function(slide) {
  slide.getShapes().forEach(function(shape) {          
    // Replacing text lines
  })
});
```

#### Note:

In order to retrieve the copied presentation, you are currently doing this:

```js
template.makeCopy(presName,DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID));
var newPresentation = DriveApp.getFilesByName(presName).next().getUrl();
var Presentation = SlidesApp.openByUrl(newPresentation);
```

There is no need to do this, you can just retrieve the `ID` of the created template, and open by `ID`, like this:

```js
var copiedTemplate = template.makeCopy(presName,DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID));
var Presentation = SlidesApp.openById(copiedTemplate.getId());
```

#### Reference:

- [Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides)
- [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)

Comment: @lamblichus Thank you, it works now! How would I be able to do the same with image urls as one of the variables that replaces {{image}} in a box? I've tried adding : 'slide.getShapes().forEach(function(picture) { picture.find("{{image}}").replace(image);'. 'picture.findText("{{image}}").replace(image);' , 'picture.getText("{{image}}").replaceWithImage(image);',  ' picture.getText().findText("{{image}}").replace(image);' . I've also thought to try '.insertImage' but that wouldn't require the placeholder in the template, would it?

Comment: @ILT I guess you should apply a combination of [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#gettext) and [replaceWithImage(imageUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#replacewithimageimageurl). In any case, considering that this was not part of the original question, I'd suggest you to post a new question regarding this, if you have doubts about how to proceed.

Comment: @ILT Also, please consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This is useful because this community relies on it to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it :)